# Resize two TextAreas inside a GridPane (Java FXML)

Tags: java, javafx, resize, fxml

I'm pretty new to FXML and don't know how to work with a GridPane. I would like to make it possible for the user to change the sizes of the two TextAreas, but relativ to each other (if one area gets smaller the other one fills the space). 
I'm also trying to build a new Layout, because the GridPane is pretty restrictive.

Belows the code:

```
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.input.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>

<VBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="550.0" prefWidth="640.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.gide.tlvconvert.app.TLVAppDocumentController">
    <children>
        <MenuBar AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
            <menus>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="_File">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleOpenAction" text="Open INI File">
                            <accelerator>
                                <KeyCodeCombination alt="DOWN" code="O" control="UP" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                            </accelerator>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleEditIniAction" text="Edit INI File">
                            <accelerator>
                                <KeyCodeCombination alt="UP" code="I" control="DOWN" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                            </accelerator>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Export Settings File">
                            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleExportEF_RULEAction" text="EF_RULE">
                            </MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleExportKEYDAction" text="EF_KEYD">
                            </MenuItem>
                        </Menu>
                        <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleCloseAction" text="Exit">
                            <accelerator>
                                <KeyCodeCombination alt="DOWN" code="F4" control="UP" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                            </accelerator>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="_Edit">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleUpperCase" text="Make Uppercase Characters">
                            <accelerator>
                                <KeyCodeCombination alt="DOWN" code="U" control="UP" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                            </accelerator>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleLowerCase" text="Make Lowercase Characters">
                            <accelerator>
                                <KeyCodeCombination alt="DOWN" code="L" control="UP" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                            </accelerator>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleSubstitute" text="Substitute">
                            <accelerator>
                                <KeyCodeCombination alt="DOWN" code="T" control="UP" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
                            </accelerator>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="_Help">
                    <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleAboutAction" text="About" />
                    </items>
                </Menu>
            </menus>
        </MenuBar>
    <GridPane alignment="CENTER" hgap="10.0" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" vgap="10.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
        <padding>
            <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
        </padding>
        <children>
            <Label fx:id="lblTlvStructure" text="TLV structure: TAG #(values) |ASCII value|" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="4" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <ComboBox fx:id="typeCombobox" layoutX="15.0" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.columnSpan="3" GridPane.rowIndex="0" onAction="#typeComboAction">
                <items>
                    <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                        <String fx:value=" -" />
                        <String fx:value="EF_RULE" />
                        <String fx:value="EF_KEYD" />
                    </FXCollections>
                </items>
            </ComboBox>
            <TextArea fx:id="textAreaTlvStructure" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" onDragDropped="#handleTlvStructureDragDropped" onDragOver="#handleTlvDragOver" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="8" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.rowSpan="6" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
               <font>
                  <Font name="Courier New Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </TextArea>
            <Label text="TLV result:" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
            <TextArea fx:id="textAreaTlvResult" onDragDropped="#handleTlvResultDragDropped" onDragOver="#handleTlvDragOver" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="8" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="8" GridPane.rowSpan="6" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
               <font>
                  <Font name="Courier New Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </TextArea>
            <HBox GridPane.columnSpan="4" GridPane.rowIndex="14">
                <children>
                    <Button fx:id="buttonBuild" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" onAction="#handleButtonBuild" prefWidth="125.0" text="Build" textAlignment="CENTER">
                        <HBox.margin>
                            <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                        </HBox.margin>
                    </Button>
                    <Button fx:id="buttonAnalyze" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" onAction="#handleButtonAnalyze" prefWidth="125.0" text="Analyze" textAlignment="CENTER">
                        <HBox.margin>
                            <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                        </HBox.margin>
                    </Button>
                    <Label fx:id="textFieldStatus" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="status messages" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                        <HBox.margin>
                            <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                        </HBox.margin>
                        <padding>
                            <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                        </padding>
                    </Label>
                </children>
            </HBox>
        </children>
        <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <ColumnConstraints />
            <ColumnConstraints />
        </columnConstraints>
            <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints />
                <RowConstraints vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                <RowConstraints />
            </rowConstraints>
            <VBox.margin>
                <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
            </VBox.margin>
        </GridPane>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

Comment: Use a [`SplitPane`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/SplitPane.html)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `GridPane` I think you would be better suited to use a `SplitPane`, it has this type of functionality built in. Below is taken from the JavaFX documentation.

```
A control that has two or more sides, each separated by a divider, which can 
be dragged by the user to give more space to one of the sides, resulting in 
the other side shrinking by an equal amount.

Nodes can be positioned horizontally next to each other, or stacked 
vertically. This can be controlled by setting the orientationProperty().
```

Below is a runnable example:

```
package com.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        SplitPane pane = new SplitPane();
        pane.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        pane.getItems().addAll(new TextArea(), new TextArea());

        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```